# Updated Vue to 3.2.3. vue --version shows as 3.0.1 still... How to fix?

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-update

I am attempting to update my Vue version to the most recent, however after running "npm install -g @vue/cli" (as told to by the vue website), it said everything ran fine and shows 3.2.3 had installed, but when running vue --version to check, it shows as 3.0.1.

I then figured I would uninstall all vue instances but, regardless of global or local uninstalls, it would always still show vue --version as 3.0.1.

No matter what I tried, I can not seem to remove vue form my system for a fresh install, nor simply update from 3.0.1 to the latest version.

Not sure what sort of indo would be best to show here?

--

Bit more info here,

I ran "Which Vue" and the result was -

```
/usr/local/bin/vue
```

I also the ran npm list -g --depth=0

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.6.0/lib
├── @vue/cli@3.2.3
└── npm@6.5.0
```

However, running - vue -V (or even vue --version) gives me just:

```
3.0.1
```

Comment: make sure you are installing the update on the same node_modules file as the older version

Comment: are you using any node manager? You might want to check your node version. Reloading your terminal might work as well

Comment: Run a `which vue` and check if the path is correct for your install location

Comment: @ErikTerwan I just done that and it says "/usr/local/bin/vue" not sure if this is supposed to be the one or not? :s If not, how do i change to the correct place?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm install -g @vue/cli` then reload your terminal.

Comment: I think this command installed Vue 2 on my system, where as I am using Vue 3. But, even after adjusting ( I believe they use vue/cli now?) it didnt seem to work. My system says it has installed, but Vue -v still shows it as 3.0.1

Comment: VueJS is a framework, the CLI is a command line interface that helps set up projects. So yes, it will install Vue @ version 2.*.* but that command line interface is 3.*.*

Comment: Check out this link for the CLI installation https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: Apologies, `vue-cli` and `vue/cli` are two different things.

Comment: I did try that already and no use (I used that to install, and again to update, and it works/installs, but upon doing the last command to check (vue --version) it shows "3.0.1" instead of the newer version (3.2.x)

Comment: Remove the old version first `npm uninstall @vue/cli -g` and then `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall vue-cli, and then install @vue/cli.
Here is how:

```sh
npm uninstall -g vue-cli  
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

3 steps to update from vue 3 lower version to the latest:

- npm install -g @vue/cli
- vue upgrade
- npm i

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have `npm` and `yarn` installed.
Try `npm update --global` and `yarn global upgrade`.

Good luck!!!